# MVC EditorFor to Title Case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor, title-case

How do you convert input value to title case in EditorFor? I know doing

```
@Html.EditorFor(model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "text-transform:uppercase" } })
```

will only change the client side so I need to change it manually on server side.

I tried adding the class `text-capitalize` but seems no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are explanations to use either title case or sentence case for viewmodel's string properties which bound to `EditorFor`:

1) If you want to use title case, you can set it inside getter part with [`ToTitleCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) method (change `CurrentCulture` to `InvariantCulture` depending on your requirements), as in example below:

```
private string _titleCase;
private System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

public string TitleCaseProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_titleCase))
        {
            return _value;
        }
        else 
        {
            return culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(_titleCase.ToLower());
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _titleCase = value;
    }
}
```

**View usage**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TitleCaseProperty, ...)
```

2) If you want sentence case instead, use regular expression to find out sequences (referenced from [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141426/net-method-to-convert-a-string-to-sentence-case)) and do similar way to getter part like above:

```
private string _sentenceCase;
private Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])|[?!.:,;]\s+(.)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

public string SentenceCaseProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sentenceCase))
        {
            return _value;
        }
        else 
        {
            return rgx.Replace(_sentenceCase.ToLower(), s => s.Value.ToUpper());
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _sentenceCase = value;
    }
}
```

**View usage**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SentenceCaseProperty, ...)
```

Live example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G3CvmP)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend performing this conversion at the getter of this property using `.ToUpper()`

```
get {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value))
     {
       return _value;
     }
   return _value.ToUpper();
 }
```

Comment: Don't these convert all data input to Uppercase? I wanted it to be sentenced/title case.

Answer (score 0):

easier method

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model.FieldName, new { @class = "uppercase" })
```

css:

```
.uppercase { text-transform:uppercase }
```